# Set Theory, Triangles, and Mathematical Spaces Corresponding to Geometric Objects

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'd like to begin by noting that I'm a chemist by training, not a mathematician. I know as much applied math as a chemist needs to know (through basic calculus), and beyond that I have only bits and pieces as an interested layman. I'm trying to scratch a curiosity itch.

I was thinking about a set, defined in an xyz coordinate system as

{(x,y,z)|x + y + z = 180; x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}.

I believe this set would define the surface (and only the surface) of a 1/8th sphere in that coordinate system.

If x, y, and z are modeled as angles, then that surface becomes a bounded mathematical space in which each point represents a triangle, and the surface defines all possible triangles.

My question is, what about the rest of the sphere? For example the interior of that 1/8th sphere is

{(x,y,z)|x + y + z < 180; x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}.

What sort of forms would that define if the coordinates are modeled as angles?

Is it just that the surface has a 1 to 1 correspondence with the set of all triangles, and the rest of the sphere...doesn't? Is it as simple as that? Or does the rest of the sphere define some weird set of non-Euclidean triangles that don't sum to 180 degrees or that have non-positive angles?

Comment: As $x + y + z = 180$ defines a plane, it is not a sphere.

Comment: Your intuition about the surface is confused by thinking of $x,y,z$ as "angles".  In an $x,y,z$-coordinate system, these values are distances along three mutually orthogonal axes (not angles).

Comment: @Przemysław Scherwentke Fair point. Treating it as a plane, what then does the rest of the space I described represent? In other words, whether it's a spherical surface or not, it still has a 1:1 correspondence with the set of all triangles, does it not? What then does the "> 180" space correspond to?

Comment: @hardmath In any coordinate system, the units are arbitrary. If we define the units as "degrees" then the plane defined by distances along the three orthogonal angles still corresponds to the set of all possible triangles.

Comment: As you wish, consider interpreting them as degrees, but it does not justify saying the points form the surface of a 1/8 sphere.  Keep in mind that 3 angles do not determine a triangle.

Comment: @hardmath I think OP considers triangles modulo homotheties and rotations (and maybe reflections). In this case, one can answer: first, the space $\mathbb R^3$ containing this plane turns to a 3-torus $(\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z)^3$, as angles $x$ and $x+2\pi n$ are the same. Second, it’s further factorized by $A_3$ of cyclic coordinate permutations, and then there are also less obvious $(x,y,z)\mapsto(-y,-x,z)$ (we could omit $-$ signs if reflections are allowed). (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) There, the plane mentioned turns into something hard to comprehend (at least at first), but all its points still do represent triangle equivalence classes. Also maybe I’ve forgot to factorize it further.

Comment: @arseniiv note that the set defines (x, y, z) > 0. Thanks for your discussion, though. That was helpful.

Comment: @hardmath "Keep in mind that 3 angles do not determine a triangle." Fair point. Even keeping the sum of all angles equal to 180 does not ipso facto limit the correspondences to triangles. It does seem though that the set defined by the plane should still be equal to the set of all triangles. That is, there is a 1:1 correspondence between the elements of both sets.